# Value automatically reducing in edittext

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an editText which is coded as follows :

```
float skm = Float.parseFloat(sqkm.getText().toString());
            hectares.setText(String.valueOf(skm * 100));
            sqm.setText(String.valueOf(skm * 1E+6));
            sqft.setText(String.valueOf(skm * 1.076E+7));
```

when the user presses any value as input, the value automatically gets reduced by a minor decimal(like 0.00001). Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a decimal type instead of floating point.